# PasswordToggle doesn't transform to custom TransformationMethod after click to visibility button

Tags: java, android, passwords, visibility

In my `xml` file, I have a password field is a `TextInputEditText` which uses a custom `PasswordTransformationMethod` to show the biggest dots when password is hidden:

```
public class MyPasswordTransformationMethod extends  PasswordTransformationMethod {
@Override
 public CharSequence getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) {
return new PasswordCharSequence(source);
  }

private class PasswordCharSequence implements CharSequence {
private CharSequence mSource;
public PasswordCharSequence(CharSequence source) {
    mSource = source; // Store char sequence
}
public char charAt(int index) {
    return '⬤';
}
public int length() {
    return mSource.length(); // Return default
}
public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
    return mSource.subSequence(start, end); // Return default
}
}
 }; text.setTransformationMethod(new MyPasswordTransformationMethod());
```

First time bullets are bigger, but when clicked on visibility to see the password and hidden it again, dots get smaller. How I can change it to always use the character defined on MyPasswordTransformationMethod?.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/textInput_create_pass"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorBlue">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText

                        android:id="@+id/edit_create_pass"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        style="@style/EditText.Password"
                        android:text=""
                        android:letterSpacing="0.5"
                        android:maxLength="6"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
                        />
```

Thanks-